# How to do an If await by the async function response

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to create a function that checks if a table already exists in the database and if it doesn't, create one
But the problem is the If doesn't await for checkTableExist()

```
const checkTableExist = async () => {
    console.log('starting check')
    db.query(`SELECT column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'users'`, async (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        if (results !== null) {
            console.log('Not exist')
            return true
        }
        console.log('Exist')
        return false
    })
}


const createTable = async () => {
    await db.connect();
    if (await checkTableExist() !== true) {
        console.log('Creating Table')
        await db.query(`CREATE TABLE users (
             id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
             name varchar(100),
             email varchar(100),
             celular varchar(11),
             password varchar(255),
             validated boolean
         )`)
         db.end()
         return
    }
    db.end()
    console.log('Table already exist')
    return
}

createTable()
```

Console Log

```
starting check
Creating Table
Not exist
```

Comment: `await db.query` in `checkTableExist` function ?

Comment: I already tried, I get the same result. VSCode says: "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression"

Comment: Why do you use `async` for callback in the `checkTableExist`?

Comment: I was doing several tests to try to fix the problem and one of the ideas was to add an async in the callback and an await in the if results like `if (await results !== null)` but that didn't work, i just forgot to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `checkTableExist` you are checking your DB Query results using a callback function. In there, when you `return`, you are not actually returning to the `createTable` function, you're getting back to `checkTableExist`.

If you use `await`, your `return`s should work correctly:

```
const checkTableExist = async () => {
  console.log('starting check')

  const results = await db.query(`SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'users'`);

  if (results !== null) {
    console.log('Not exist')
    return true
  }
  console.log('Exist')
  return false
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  Sorry i'm a noob and I'm making a lot of silly mistakes